# WordPress - Preview of latest wordpress blog post in iframe

Tags: wordpress

I have a website and a blog. I want to insert an iframe into the website, displaying the latest post from the blog.

So I need just the post content inside the iframe, without wordpress headers and sidebars.

Whats the best approach to achieve this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the site and the blog are on the same domain, you may be best off querying the latest post using the Wordpress API itself, making it unnecessary to fiddle with an iframe.

How to do that is described in [Integrating WordPress with Your Website](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) on the WordPress Codex.

If you *need* to do this using an iframe, I guess it's easiest to set up a new theme that doesn't display anything but the post itself. That would be some work though.

Answer (score 1):

I recently put together a video tutorial of how I did this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GuocgQlCmw

I didn't get rid of the WordPress sidebar, but the tutorial shows how I used Firebug to get rid of parts of the header and the same technique should work for the sidebar. There are links in the youtube description to all the reference material I used including a link to a blog entry I wrote describing the process.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer the question but why don't you use Wordpress for all of your website if you use templates you can make it look like a website and also have a blog. Have a look at this site i made using just Wordpress http://www.smkrc.co.uk. By doing this you would have access to the posts and would not need to use iframes.